# How to change the filename of the pdf generated from blob (navbar title) in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

Below code we are using to generate Pdf from Blob. Once the link is clicked I need to open the pdf in new tab with proper filename not as above auto generated string from blob.

```
downloadDocument = (fileContent) => {
        const pdfContent = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(fileContent);
        const pdfBlob = new Blob([pdfContent], { type: DOWNLOAD_PDF.PDF_TYPE });

        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
        const newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.location.href = url;
    };
```

```
base64ToArrayBuffer = (base64) => {
        const binaryString = window.atob(base64);
        const binaryLen = binaryString.length;
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);

        for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i += 1) {
            const ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
            bytes[i] = ascii;
        }

        return bytes;
    };
```

Need to change the file name and url of the Blob pdf.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk61E.png

Answer (score 0):

use an anchor tag and set the download attribute with the filename you want also set `link.target` to _blank to open it in a new tab

```js
downloadDocument = (fileContent, fileName) => {
    const pdfContent = this.base64ToArrayBuffer(fileContent);
    const pdfBlob = new Blob([pdfContent], { type: DOWNLOAD_PDF.PDF_TYPE });
    // use an anchor tag
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
    // Set the download attribute to specify the desired filename
    link.download = fileName;
    link.target = "_blank"; // set this to _blank to open it in a new tab
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
};
```

Comment: The above solution will only work when we try to download with specific filename. But in my case i need to open the pdf in new tab with navbar title as my filename

Comment: Can you please consider my point. Please ask question if you are not clear on my point